# cannot navigate to main screen in react native

Tags: react-native

My code has a main screen. The main screen has one button which navigates to screen1. Screen1 has a button which navigates to screen2. The button in screen2 won't navigate to main screen.

But when I type this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen1') in screen2, It works. What is the error?
All 3 screens are added in stack navigator.

This is the button navigating to timetable: **Main screen**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

export default class EndClass extends Component {
    render() {
      return(
        <View>
          <TouchableHighlight
            style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.signupButton]} 
            onPress ={() =>  this.props.navigation.navigate('TimeTable')}
          >
            <Text style={styles.signUpText}>end! </Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>  
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your navigator and button code?

Comment: you just edit you question with code snippet so that we can understand the problem